# Why eclipse suggest me to remove override annotations within spinner onItemSelected

Tags: android, spinner

I don't have any idea with this case, the eclipse suggest me to remove `@Override` in the `spinner.onItemSelected`? But I know that the itemselected should look like this

```
spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id)
        {
            Object item = parentView.getItemAtPosition(position);
            value = item.toString();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView)
        {

        }
    });
```

do you have any idea why eclipse suggest me to remove it?
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

go to Eclipse properties (not project specific, to the whole Eclipse) in the tree menu:

Java -> Compiler -> JDK Compliance
and change it to 1.6.

It should stop suggesting you to remove the override.

Comment: no. 1.6 is the usually used on any Android project. Be sure to clean the project after you change this.